# How do you right align headerTitle in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to right align my header title in my react native app but can't seem to do so. In react navigation, you can set `headerTitleAlign` prop only to center and left. I try to use `headerRight` and remove `headerTitle` but the default title kicks in which is the name of the screen.

Had a search online but no answers has cropped up.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your header inside a view. And pass this style ={{alignItems: 'flex-end', alignContents: 'flex-end'}}